# Making form fields conditionally read only (PHP)

Tags: php, html, mysql

Let's say I have several series of form fields in table rows: f1, f2, f3; g1, g2, g3; h1, h2, h3 etc.

Now let's say that I have a username stored in a PHP session variable that may match a field value in one of those series. Here, the field value that might be a match would be f1(echo $row['pers1Name']), g1(echo $row['user1Name']) or h1(echo $row['manage1Name']).

I need to lock the form down so that ONLY the fields that pertain to the session user are editable. All others need to be read only. For example, if the session username == $row['pers1Name'], then how can I make it so that f2, f3 are editable but g1-g3, h1-h3 are not? It seems like a job for a loop, but my attempts have only been partially successful.

```
for($i=1; $i<=6; $i++)
 {
   if($_SESSION['userName'] != $row['pers'.$i.'Name'])
   {
     $readonly = ' readonly';
   }
 }
```

The obvious problem here is that, even if a match is found, the other values will not match, and every field where I echo $readonly gets locked.  Am I on the right track, at least?

Comment: That's invalid syntax, your missing a closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the value in an array, with the `$row['pers'.$i.'Name']` as the key -

```
for($i=1; $i<=6; $i++){
   if($_SESSION['userName'] != $row['pers'.$i.'Name'])
   {
     $readonly[$row['pers'.$i.'Name']] = ' readonly';
   }
   else {
     $readonly[$row['pers'.$i.'Name']] = '';
   }
}
```

Comment: Awesome. So, should I echo the variable thus?

    <?php echo $readonly[$row['pers'.$i.'Name']]; ?>

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, you need to reinitilize  $readonly;

```
    for($i=1; $i<=6; $i++)
     {
       $readonly ='';
       if($_SESSION['userName'] != $row['pers'.$i.'Name'])
       {
         $readonly = ' readonly';
       }
     }
```